# Is it possible to Unit-Test a OpenID-Connect Token Validation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jwt, openid-connect, shiro

I want to build some unit-tests for my JWT Validation Scripts. I'm extending Shiro with some custom Token-Validation scripts for openid-connect usage.

The problem is, that the method i tryed to test validates an already expired token. If i want to use a valid token for the tests, i need to make a new request to the OAuth-Provider to get it and i don't know the new values of the token which are important for unit-test matching. Now I'm questioning myself if this falls under the area of an unit-test because I thought unit-tests are just simple prepared test where the result is compared to the method output.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would give a virtual current time to the unit test as an additional input parameter. The unit test can perform validation on time-related claims such as `exp`, `iat` and `nbf` using the virtual current time as if it were the actual current time.

As a good practice, when you write a library which changes its behavior based on the current time, the library should be able to accept a base time as an optional input parameter.

Comment: Thats a good point! But i have the problem that there is a token-validation method inside of the method i want to unit-test. Im not able to give in a virtual time. So i have to request a new token from the provider to validate the functionality of the method. Is this still a unit-test or another type of test?